# headphones not working in 13.10 after update on my AW m17x

Tags: 13.10, headphones

My headphones is not work on my Alienware M17x after recent update from 13.04 to 13.10. In the Sound window no headphones option.

```
H/W path         Device      Class          Description    
                             system         M17xR4 (xxx123x#ABA)
/0                           bus            M17xR4
/0/0                         memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                         processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.
/0/4/b                       memory         32KiB L1 cache

/0/4/c                       memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/4/d                       memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/a                         memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/2e                        memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/2e/0                      memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MH
/0/2e/1                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MH
/0/2e/2                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/2e/3                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MH
/0/100                       bridge         3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controll
/0/100/1                     bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core process
/0/100/1/0                   generic        Illegal Vendor ID
/0/100/2                     display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Cont
/0/100/14                    bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/16                    communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1a                    bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1b                    multimedia     7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1c                    bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1c/0      eth0        network        AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
/0/100/1c.2                  bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1c.2/0    wlan0       network        Centrino Wireless-N 2230
/0/100/1c.3                  bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1c.3/0                generic        RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.3/0.1              generic        RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1d                    bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/100/1f                    bridge         HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                  storage        82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID m
/0/100/1f.3                  bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
/0/1             scsi0       storage        
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda    disk           750GB WDC WD7500BPKT-7
/0/1/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1   volume         111GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2   volume         139GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3   volume         200GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2             scsi1       storage        
/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/sdb    disk           128GB ADATA SP900
/0/2/0.0.0/1     /dev/sdb1   volume         46GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2/0.0.0/2     /dev/sdb2   volume         70GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2/0.0.0/3     /dev/sdb3   volume         1940MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/3             scsi2       storage        
/0/3/0.0.0       /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW GA31N
/1                           power          DELL 7XC9N34A
total 0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 33 Oct 23 19:15 timer
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  1 Oct 23 19:15 seq
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  7 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D4c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  8 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 11 Oct 23 19:15 hwC0D3
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 12 Oct 23 19:15 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 13 Oct 23 19:15 controlC0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       60 Oct 23 19:15 by-path
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      340 Oct 23 19:15 .
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  4 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  3 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  2 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 10 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  6 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D1c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  5 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  9 Oct 23 19:15 pcmC0D0p
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root     4400 Oct 23 19:27 ..
cat: /dev/sndstat: No such file or directory
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] [10de:1212] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
09:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:8127 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0520 Alienware Corporation 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/usr/sbin/alsactl
Specified filename /dev/dsp does not exist.
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  marc       2215 F.... pulseaudio
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *bin/slmodemd*
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.276252] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.551392] Found 1 acpi root devices
[    0.625052] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 12 devices
[    0.925105] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.925118] type=2000 audit(1382526929.892:1): initialized
[    1.166855] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.181054] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.181142] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.197064] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.197140] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.197473] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.197552] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.197841] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.197914] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.280570] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    1.310358] sdhci-pci 0000:09:00.1: SDHCI controller found [10ec:5209] (rev 1)
[    1.310415] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
[    1.310417] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    1.625853] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.626223] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.870056] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.870423] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.056437] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    2.259544] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=00db
[    2.259747] usb 3-4: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.259751] usb 3-4: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.440036] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=187c, idProduct=0520
[    2.603299] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=8127
[    2.770904] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    3.499617] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    3.595278] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    3.613259] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    3.616435] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.616443] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.616447] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.616940] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.616946] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.617217] type=1400 audit(1382526932.830:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=430 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=450 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.637669] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Integer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    3.637708] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Integer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    3.637732] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Integer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    3.637758] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Integer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    3.689724] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD (064e:8127)
[    3.690283] uvcvideo: No streaming interface found for terminal 9.
[    4.684258] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    4.725161] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.839735] type=1400 audit(1382526934.050:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=935 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=939 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.839743] type=1400 audit(1382526934.050:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=935 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=939 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.840258] type=1400 audit(1382526934.054:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=935 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=939 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.205584] init: alsa-restore main process (1100) terminated with status 19
[    5.247699] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores.
[    5.426860] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[    5.426863] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[    5.426873] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    5.428410] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    5.454729] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[    5.566769] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    5.566845] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    5.566914] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    5.566976] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    5.567036] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   73.079705] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 1/3)
[   73.281180] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 2/3)
[   73.879883] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 3/3)
[   74.728337] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 1/3)
[   74.929821] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 2/3)
[   75.133855] wlan0: direct probe to 4c:e6:76:c4:cc:0a (try 3/3)
sudo: /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon: command not found
    Release Date: 06/29/2012
    Manufacturer: Alienware
    Product Name: M17xR4
    Serial Number: BVPRZW1
    Manufacturer: Alienware
    Product Name: M17xR4
    Serial Number: .BVPRZW1.CN129612981009.
    Manufacturer: Alienware
    Serial Number: BVPRZW1
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Option 1: String1 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 2: String2 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 3: String3 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Option 4: String4 for Type12 Equipment Manufacturer
    Manufacturer: A-DATA Technology
    Serial Number: 000027BA
    Manufacturer: Hynix
    Serial Number: 42BA831E
    Manufacturer: Empty
    Serial Number: Empty
    Manufacturer: Hynix
    Serial Number: 42AA8339
    Manufacturer: SDI
    SBDS Serial Number: 0001
    SBDS Manufacture Date: 2009-01-01
snd_seq_dummy          12798  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41070  1 
snd_hda_codec_ca0132    36039  1 
btusb                  28267  0 
bluetooth             371874  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_intel          48171  3 
snd_hda_codec         188852  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102033  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  3 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  4 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69141  18 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_dummy,snd_hda_codec_ca0132,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   101512  5 hid_generic,hid_microsoft,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 4
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0:  26% 1:  26%
            0: -35.00 dB 1: -35.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume:  71%
                 -9.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: yes
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 5
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "CA0132 Analog"
        alsa.id = "CA0132 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc4710000 irq 47"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1e20"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel PantherPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:11020011,1028057b,00100918 HDA:80862806,1028057b,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
>>> **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-ca0132 snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-ca0132 snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-ca0132 snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
Support status summary of 'Xware':

You have 2326 packages (88.5%) supported until July 2014 (9m)

You have 44 packages (1.7%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 258 packages (9.8%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c4710000-c4713fff
```